# How to upgrade ant-design in project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, antd

I want to user new component from antd, but it added in 3.12.0 and my current version in project reactjs  is 3.10.9. So how i can upgrade my antd ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your antd dependency in package.json with new version (3.12.0 instead of 3.10.9) then Go to package.json directory in your CMD and run

**npm install** or **yarn install**